# The date is frozen for tomorrow, not today

Tags: python, django

```
 # -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

from __future__ import unicode_literals

import base64

from datetime import timedelta, datetime
from freezegun import freeze_time

from django.conf import settings
from django.core.urlresolvers import reverse
from django.core.management import call_command
from django.test import Client
from django.core.files.uploadedfile import SimpleUploadedFile


class timetravel(object):
    """
    Fast forward in time with simulated CRON jobs (used for unit testing)
    """
    delta = None

    def __init__(self, *args):
        self.initial_now = datetime.now()
        if isinstance(args[0], timedelta):
            self.delta = args[0]
            self.now = datetime.now() + self.delta
        elif isinstance(args[0], datetime):
            self.now = args[0]
            if args[0] > self.initial_now:
                self.delta = args[0] - self.initial_now
            else:
                self.delta = self.initial_now - args[0]
        else:
            print("Please provide a datetime or timedelta object as argument")

        # import IPython
        # IPython.embed()

       #self.now = self.initial_now
       #self.freezer = freeze_time(self.now)
       #self.freezer.start()

    def __enter__(self):
        # Traveling in the past, we don't run cron jobs backward
        if self.now < self.initial_now:
            self.now = self.now - self.delta
            self.freezer = freeze_time(self.now)

            # import IPython
            # IPython.embed()

            self.freezer.start()
        # Traveling in the future, run cron jobs
        else:
            self.now = self.initial_now
            self.freezer = freeze_time(self.now)
            self.freezer.start()
            hours   = self.delta.total_seconds() / 60 / 60
            weekday = self.now.weekday()
            month   = self.now.month
            year    = self.now.year
            for i in range(1, int(hours)+1):
                call_command('cron', hourly=True, verbosity=0)
                if weekday != self.now.weekday():
                    weekday = self.now.weekday()
                    call_command('cron', daily=True)
                if self.now.weekday() == 6 and weekday != self.now.weekday():
                    call_command('cron', weekly=True)
                if self.now.month != month:
                    month = self.now.month
                    call_command('cron', monthly=True)
                if self.now.year != year:
                    year = self.now.year
                    call_command('cron', yearly=True)
                self.freezer.stop()
                self.now = self.now + timedelta(hours=1)
                self.freezer = freeze_time(self.now)
                self.freezer.start()
        return self.now
        # import IPython
        # IPython.embed()

    def __exit__(self, *args):
        self.freezer.stop()
```

I have an issue with `timetravel`. Normally, it should fixe the time in argument, but it is not the case here.

```
 def test_product_reg_p01_1month(self):
        with timetravel(datetime(2017, 03, 14)) as now:
            self._test_product_configurations(**{
                'loan_config': {
                    'product-id'        : 1,
                    'frequency'         : '1month',
                    'first_debit_date'  : now + timedelta(days=17),
                    'second_debit_date' : now
                },

                'product_config':{
                   ...

                },
            }
            )
```

Normally, the the class `timetravel` should fix the current date in the code. In `test_product_reg_p01_1month`, we call the `context manager` with `timetravel` with argument `datetime(2017, 03, 14)`. If we query the database, we obtain

```
In [2]: customer_product.deposit_date                                               
Out[2]: FakeDate(2017, 3, 14)                                                       

In [3]: datetime.now()                                                              
Out[3]: FakeDatetime(2017, 3, 13, 23, 55, 54, 708200)
```

However, `datetime.now()` should be equal to the date of tomorrow.

Thanks!

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is not a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: are there timezones involved? Agree with the comment above, try to narrow down your problem, it will be easier to find a solution.